# Angular project architecture for enterprise level application

Tags: angular

I am looking for a sample Angular project architecture for enterprise level application. For example it should have things like 1) Multi models (including core and shared module) 2) Structuring folders 3) Generic HTTP service 4) Error handling etc.. and more...
Please help me in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.jhipster.tech/ (it's free) it's bundle with a bunch of useful tech and you have a multi module archi etc. Quite useful for starting a project from scratch. Already used in large scale enterprise.

From time to time you will have to clean the generated project because you won't use all the possibilities but it's a huge timesaver.

You can launch a new app in less than 10min. And you'll have a login page, admin page, the backend preconfigured etc.

Answer (score 0):

For my company, we bought the 'fury' angular template on themeforest website. It separates all the UI to its own module, your project would be in another module all sitting under the main angular module. But you can add more modules if you need to reuse them. It's up to you which way you like to structure your module. Let's say you have a login page, I personally prefer to keep the login hmtl page, login model and login ts code in the same 'Login' folder. Makes it much easier to maintain going forward, before I separated them out to a 'Model' folder, a 'Views' folder etc but then I was hopping all over the place to find stuff.